# Hadoop rack awareness configuration

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using Hadoop and I need to configure rack awareness. Can anyone give me me an idea or a tutorial about how it works?

I'm using Hadoop 1.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking for tutorials and guidance, here are few links that are more than enough to know about setting up rack-awareness :

1. http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_hdfs_admin_tools/content/ch05.html
2. https://bigdataprocessing.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/hadoop-rack-awareness-and-configuration/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rack topology, in the context of Hadoop, defines how machines are physically located in rack in the data center. Combined with traditional network design and top of rack switching, this allows us to infer how close machines are to one another, logically, in terms of network connectivity. The physical locality of machines also has a bearing on other concerns such as power infrastructure, which is critical to understanding the possible fault domains in the system.

Rack topology is configured in Hadoop by implementing a script that, when given a list of hostnames or IP addresses on the command line, prints the rack in which the machine is located, in order. The implementation of the topology script is entirely up to the administrator and may be as simple as a shell script that has a hardcoded list of machines and rack names, or as sophisticated as a C executable that reads data from a relational database. One of the most common types of scripts is one that uses a CSV file of machine to rack mappings.

here is one example of it

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/topology_rack_awareness_scripts

Comment: Thank you for you answer, and for the informations.
I tried the example in http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/topology_rack_awareness_scripts 
and it's not working
because when i type : hadoop dfsadmin -report it doesn't show me on with rack datanode is located.
Can you try it and tell me if it works for you?

I'm using hadoop 1.2.1

Comment: Another link: http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1-latest/bk_system-admin-guide/content/admin_configure_rack_awareness.html